# Is it possible to have a large area in a d3 mercator map that can be hovered/touched to display a tooltip?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mercator

I can only get a tooltip to display over text in an area of a Mercator map, but I would like to have it display over a larger area (especially since it is difficult to touch on mobile devices).

```
paths.selectAll("text")
    .data(wards.features)
    .enter()
    .append("svg:text")
    .text(function(d){
        return (d.properties.SCODE_NAME);
        })
    .attr("x", function(d){
        return path2.centroid(d)[0];
        })
    .attr("y", function(d){
        return  path2.centroid(d)[1];
        })
    .attr("text-anchor","middle")
    .attr("font-size","24px")

    .on('mouseover',function(d){
      tip.show(d);

       d3.select(this)
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .style("stroke","black") // was white
        .style("stroke-width",1);
      })

    .on('mouseout', function(d){
      tip.hide(d);

      d3.select(this)
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .style("stroke","black")
        .style("stroke-width",0.3);
    })
 ;
```

Comment: you included non relevant part of the code, add a working snippet would help addressing your issue.

Comment: Is there any reason `tip.show(d)` would not work for the shape objects?

Comment: Not sure I know what you consider the relevant part of the code.  tip is from d3-tip which I downloaded from https://github.com/VACLab/d3-tip

Comment: Ok, then I'd recommend you add the `.on()` functions to the portion of your code where the map shapes are drawn. The relevant part of the code would be the section you draw the shapes - that's where you'd place the mouse event listeners. Also, using code snippets or jsfiddle or something would make this easier to debug.

Comment: The section where I draw the shape is used to display some text in the centre of the shape. I had the "on" code there (see above). Can I change that code to specify that the code applies to the entire shape not just the text?

Comment: I've added the entire code to jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/PatriciaW/8uhojxpg/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by moving the "on" code to the selectAll where I set the colour of the wards.